# main() function without return type

Tags: c, program-entry-point

Reading a document which is dated 1988, I found a `main()` function starting in this way:

```
main(argc, argv)
char *argv[];
{
    //some statements...
}
```

Surprisingly, I noticed there is no return type and even no data type for the arguments of the function - except for `argv[]` that is declared once more on the second line of the code.
Taking these considerations into account, my questions are: is that a valid syntax? If yes, why C language syntax is a bit different, nowadays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the original, pre-1989 "K&R" function syntax.  The return type (and even the parameter types) defaulted to int, and the parentheses contained only the names of the parameters, with their fully-typed declarations (if necessary) appearing before the first `{`.